# Where Sharia laws are punishable by death, does Islam allow exile as an alternative?

Tags: sharia

It is claimed, for example, that women in tight clothes will be executed by the Taliban.

Apparently this is because Islamic Sharia law dictates this.

It occurs to me that the Taliban's international relations problems will be somewhat diminished if they simply exiled those who were 'incompatible' with Sharia. Does Islam, or these 'flavors' of Islam,  allow exile as an alternative to execution?

Comment: Please, downvoters help me to understand the errors in my question by commenting. The question is asked in good faith and ignorance.

Comment: Not a real question. The first 2 questions are false assumptions... I suggest this question instead: **Does Islam punish women for wearing tight clothes? If so, what is the punishement?**

Comment: @NabilKadimi For people like me, it is entirely obvious that "Islam" punishes women, otherwise the Taliban would not do it, and that part was merely example. I think the Taliban execute people for violation of Sharia law. The Taliban are Islam and therefore Islam executes people. Would exile suffice?

Comment: Perhaps my question should be "Is Sharia Islam?". To be clear, I am not looking for arguments here. Just understanding.

Comment: **"Is Sharia Islam?"** This is a very good question. Please do it... My short answer would be that Islam is the religion and Sharia is the laws within that religion.


**"The Taliban are Islam"**, No, Islam is the religion they (like me and other muslims) claim to adhere to. Who's following islam correctly is proven by how well they follow the rules/instructions/laws of the Coran (the book)and the Sunna (the way of the prophet peace upon him). The Coran and the Sunna are Islam.

Comment: Also, Prophet Mohammed peace upon him said: "My ummah (nation) will divide into 73 sects, all of them will be in the Fire except for one, and that is the Jamā’ah." It was said, "And who are they, O Allah’s Messenger?” He (peace upon him) responded, "That which I and my Companions are upon today."

This shows that 72 sects says they follow islam but they actually don't (some partially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the law that has being violated. Wearing tight clothes is not punishable by execution in Shariah, rather it is something which falls under a *Tazir* and the ruler has the option to choose what punishment to give depending on the circumstances of the case. And here exile could be an option. See [Is there an legal punishment for not wearing hijab according to sharia?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67398/).

On the other hand, there are some crimes (which fall under *Hudud* and *Qisas*) where execution is obligatory once certain conditions are fulfilled (such as adequate evidence being established). These for example include murder, adultery, apostasy etc. Here the miscreant can only be punished by execution and it is not permissible to only exile them. The reason is that for these crimes execution is ordained by scriptural texts and not following them is not an option. The following verses were specifically revealed about changing punishments for crimes that have been fixed by Allah (see [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1700a)):

> ومن لم يحكم بما أنزل الله فأولئك هم الكافرون
>
> And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the disbelievers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:44](https://quran.com/5/44?translations=20)</sup>

> وأن احكم بينهم بما أنزل الله ولا تتبع أهواءهم
>
> And judge, [O Muhammad], between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:49](https://quran.com/5/49?translations=20)</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks for your info. Is this Shariah law or Islamic law or are they the same thing?

Comment: What does Tazir mean?

Comment: @Frank Shariah is the law, we often see muslim clerics combine Islam and Shariah into "The Islamic Shariaah". e.g. "The Islamic Shariaah rejects and condemns terrorism".