# Punishing zina with lashes and stoning in the 21st century

Tags: quran, hudud

Is it an Islamic obligation for Muslim rulers even today to punish fornicators with 100 lashes and adulterers by stoning to death? Can other forms of punishment like fines, jail time, etc. replace the punishments shown in the Quran and Sunnah? I have also heard the argument that the punishments of lashes and stoning are circumstantial and applicable mainly to people of the time the Quran was revealed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Sharia laws are punishable by death, does Islam allow exile as an alternative?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71762/where-sharia-laws-are-punishable-by-death-does-islam-allow-exile-as-an-alternat)

Comment: @UmH JazakAllah Khayran for the response. So your answer is no: `The reason is that for these crimes execution is ordained by scriptural texts and not following them is not an option. The following verses were specifically revealed about changing punishments for crimes that have been fixed by Allah...`